# Git unable to start Xcode from Terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, git, macos

**After edit a cloned repo. I tried committing the repo from my terminal on Mac OS Mojeva. it threw this Error:**
*"hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... fatal: cannot run Xcode: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'Xcode'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."*

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any error in the result of

```
git config --global core.editor
```

It should read `xed -w` for XCode editor to work ([XCode text editor invocation tool](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/xed-open-xcode-from-the-command-line.html)).
Make sure your `$PATH` does include that editor folder.

Comment: When I entered "git config --global core.editor" the output was "Xcode"

Comment: When I tried launch the Xcode itself from the terminal. It threw an error after I entered the command "xed -x" or "ted ---launch". The Error; " 2018-11-30 09:59:49.684 xed[894:36279] Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10024 "errAECantPutThatThere / telDNDTypeNotSupp: in make new, duplicate, etc. class can't be an element of container  / DND type is not supported by this tool " UserInfo={ErrorNumber=-10024} "

Comment: @Dreamskeepmeup can you try with xed -w instead of XCode (after checking on the command line that xed does launch XCode)?

Comment: Nothing showed after I entered xed -w instead it took me to the next line